# Outlook meeting schedules in UTC not EST

Tags: c#, email, datetime, outlook, timezone

I am successfully sending an email meeting request to the user I need. The meeting times are from 8:30am to 9:00am. When the user receives the email and invitation it is in UTC time. Meaning that the meeting is from 4:30am to 5:00am. This is not and Outlook timezone issues as mine is set to EST. I have tried to specify using `DateTime` and other methods but none of them work. Why could this always be in UTC whether I specify or not?

```
                SmtpClient MyMail = new SmtpClient("000.000.000.00");
                MyMail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

                msg.From = new MailAddress("noreply@xxxx.org", "noreply@xxxx.org");
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxx@xxxx.org", "Your Name"));
                msg.Subject = "Send Calendar Appointment Email";
                msg.Body = "Here is the Body Content";

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
                str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//A");
                str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
                str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
                str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

                str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", "20170822T083000Z"));
                //specifying what time zone
                var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
                DateTime easternTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);

                str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", easternTime));

                str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", "20170822T090000Z"));
                str.AppendLine("LOCATION: Here");
                str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
                str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
                str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
                str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
                str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));

                str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

                str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
                str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
                str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
                str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
                str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
                str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
                str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
                System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
                ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
                AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);

                MyMail.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was this line:

`str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", "20170822T090000Z"));`

Removing the 'z' from the time specified stops it from linking with a timezone.